# What is the better strategy for notifying the client that a webhook has been received by the server?

Tags: node.js, sockets, mongoose, sails.js, webhooks

There are two methods I am considering. One is to set up a subscriber function with the socket ID that is fired once the webhook is received. The other is to poll the server from the client to check if the DB has been updated.

I don't like the idea of polling the server because it is making unnecessary network calls. However, the problem I see with the subscription method is that if the socket connection disappears for whatever reason, the client will never be notified.

I am using Sails.js and Mongoose